# How to restart macro in PowerPoint VBA by changing slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am creating a timer in PowerPoint VBA and I would like it to restart when the user presses back on the remote control. For this, I used this sub:

```
Private Sub PPTEvent_SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    Call Tmr
End Sub
```

But nothing happens when I press back (or left arrow key). I would also like the macro to start when I open the PowerPoint document and I thought that would have been done by a `Sub Auto_Open()` command, placed in a module. Nope.

I would be crazy happy for a tiny bit of help!

Comment: Jenny, I may have an answer for you, but need to clarify first: Are you looking for the *same* slide to rebuild and the timer to start over when the user clicks back or is the timer always going to be on the *previous* page (and hence you would need the timer on every slide)?

Comment: Hi Otaku!

The plan is to only have one single slide in the whole presentation. So when I click the back button, the same slide will restart and set the counter to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which verion you are using. You might like to try [`one of these events`](http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/events_version.html), `OnSlideShowPageChange` for example.